# Efficiently extracting a column value from when a flag changes into a new column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have data that gets restated weekly. In the table below, I receive columns Date, Product, Location, Rate, FlagA, and FlagB. FlagC is a computed column which flags the record where FlagA = 1 as a 1 if FlagB has been flagged as 1 in any future records. Similarly, I need to create a computed column called FlagC_Rate which pulls the value in the Rate column for the row where FlagB = 1 (e.g., 0.06 in this case). Any thoughts on what select statement I should write to get that FlagC_Rate value? I copied my code for the FlagC column as reference.

CODE FOR CALCULATING FLAGC column:

```
Select (SUM(case when FlagB = 1 then 1 else null end) OVER(Partition by product, location)) 
* (case when FlagA = 1 then 1 else null end) as FlagC FROM Table
```

ATTEMPT for FLAGC_RATE

```
Select (SUM(case when FlagB = 1 then 1 else null end) OVER(Partition by product, location)) 
* (case when FlagA = 1 then 1 else null end) * (case when FlagB = 1 then Rate else null end) as FLAGC_Rate FROM Table
```

SAMPLE DATA AND EXAMPLE FOR HOW I'M TRYING TO POPULATE FLAGC_RATE

January Data

```
Date          Product    Location  Rate    FlagA   FlagB   FlagC FlagC_Rate
Jan 2020      WidgetA        X     0.05      1       0       0      NULL
```

February Data (FlagC columns get restated and populated)

```
Date          Product    Location  Rate    FlagA   FlagB   FlagC FlagC_Rate
Jan 2020      WidgetA        X     0.05      1       0       1      0.06
Feb 2020      WidgetA        X     0.06      0       1       0      NULL
```

March Data (Flag C columns are nulls since each product/location pairing will only see one record that has values for FlagC and FlagC_Rate)

```
Date          Product    Location  Rate    FlagA   FlagB   FlagC FlagC_Rate
Jan 2020      WidgetA        X     0.05      1       0       1      0.06
Feb 2020      WidgetA        X     0.06      0       1       0      NULL
March 2020    WidgetA        X     0.06      0       0       0      NULL
```

Comment: Sorry, posted my attempt now.

Comment: @R.Joe Are you updating the values or have created the computed column?

Comment: @sacse - please see my updated question.. does that make sense?

Comment: @R.Joe that seems like computed column but could be a trigger too, can you please add the screenshot of the computed column logic as the expression doesn't seem correct to me?

Comment: @sacse - hmm, I can't take a screenshot of the code since I did simplify it for this example. I can confirm the express for FlagC column works correctly.

Comment: @R.Joe ok, np, can you please update [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e4556a5b075f0c30a8f7984015a9c87)?

Comment: @sacse - does this  work: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fbe01590de16522115d1cd1ea0acbff) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
Select *
, SUM(case when FlagB = 1 then 1 else null end) OVER(Partition by product, location) * (case when FlagA = 1 then 1 else null end) as FlagC
, max(case when FlagB = 1 then Rate else null end) OVER(Partition by product, location) * (case when FlagA = 1 then 1 else null end) as FLAGC_Rate 
from data_table
```

Please see the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5e8c81c042de24188a9188cdfe1b1b1a)**.